# ECM Platform or custom ASP.NET Web Application?

Tags: asp.net, .net, sharepoint, web-applications, sensenet

I've been asked to develop a .NET web application with the following requirements and features:

- Moderate software license expenses
- .NET Web Application
- Document storage (with change history, although a complete CMS is not needed)
- Complex data model

  - Extensible and groupable object attributes
  - Private/public field visibility
  - Non-trivial relationships between database tables
- Custom alert configuration (screen and e-mail notifications) about approaching due dates, missing documentation, etc.
- Resource access control & user management (roles and groups)
- High user volume (several thousands of users)
- Many complex and dynamic forms
- Search engine
- Statistical reporting
- Bulk data & metadata upload and download
- Simple data migration
- REST API for external integration
- Multilanguage
- Full-featured mobile version (for tablets and smartphones)
- Corporate look and feel

These are the options I have considered:

1. SharePoint Foundation 2013 + Custom Web Parts + Custom DB + Document Libraries
2. Sense/Net + Custom Web Parts + Custom DB + Document Libraries
3. Custom ASP.NET Web Application

What approach would you recommend? Also, can you please make a recommendation on the following points?

- Server characteristics and topology
- Application architecture
- Scalability
- Search capabilities
- Reporting tools
- Persistence framework
- Document storage (MS Office)
- Mobility

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I work for Sense/Net, which I want to put out there to be fair.

However, even if I wouldn't be, I'd still recommend looking at our solution based on the criteria you outlined. What you are planning to build seems to be really custom stuff and from experience, I can say that projects like this never changing. Going for an open-source application would definately be my choice, in order to make sure I don't hit a wall later down the line.

Sense/Net is practically capable of delivering everything you need out of the box, but of course, customization will be needed.

From a licensing perspective, you would also be better off probably, since we only lincense the CPU cores, not the thousands of users benefitting from the system.

Writing a custom application from scratch with these requierements would make no sense in my opinion as the costs would be well over the one of a readymade solution (whichever you choose).

The things need to be clarified are the reporting tools you will need and whether you need a native application for mobile devices (or would something working in their browsers would be sufficient).

I can see that this answer is well overdue, but if the topic is still of interest and you havent done so yet, drop us an e-mail through our website and we can help you out in finding the perfect solution!